# Why is my browser echoing this text backwards?

Tags: php

I have this written in PHP:

```
<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();
?>
<div style="float: right; text-align: right;">
<h4>
    <?php
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
     echo 'Welcome: ' . $current_user->user_login; 
    ?>
</h4>
<p>
    <?php
        echo '<a>My Classes</a> &nbsp;&brvbar;&nbsp; <a>Logout</a>';
    } else {
    ?>
</p>
<h4>    
    <?php
      echo 'Welcome, guest!';
   ?>
</h4>
<p>
    <?php
        echo '<a>Login</a> | <a>Register</a>';
    }
    ?>
</p>
</div>
```

And my browser is showing this:

```
Welcome: Admin
| LogoutMy Classes
```

Why is that?

Comment: hahahah that's an insasne behaviour ahahah

Comment: then what you want as output?

Comment: @Keith have you removed the &brvbar; entity to see if that affects the display at all?  also, is it flipped around in the html source like that as well?

Comment: I want it to output: My Classes | Logout

Comment: Yes I removed all HTML entities, still the same.

Comment: @Keith, can you please inspect the DOM and copy paste the html as it appears there, for the whole login bit?

Comment: What's the actual markup that's generated?

Comment: Try setting `overflow:auto;`  in the div style.  Also see what `overflow: visible;` looks like

Comment: Do you have any formatting to < a > tags in your CSS?

Comment: Which browser? I've tried Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, and they all appear to work as expected.

Comment: Also it works fine in Safari.

Comment: Using Chrome. Thanks for your input all, Looks like The answer was posted! stackexchange = love

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the look of it, you've got your `<a>` tags floated to the right. That being the case, right floated elements will always stack right to left.

What this means is that the first element that is floated to the right will sit on the far right edge, and the second element will float on the right, but sit on the **left** side of the first element. To fix this, you'll have to either (a) adjust your CSS so that the `<a>` tags don't float on the right, or (b) re-order your echo statement to output "Logout" before your output "My Classes".

Comment: yep, that's right. That's what did it. I'm trying to fumble through building a login and forgot something basic!